# How to decrypt a password from SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, hash, passwords

I have this query in sql server 2000:

```
select pwdencrypt('AAAA')
```

which outputs an encrypted string of 'AAAA':

```
0x0100CF465B7B12625EF019E157120D58DD46569AC7BF4118455D12625EF019E157120D58DD46569AC7BF4118455D
```

**How can I convert (decrypt) the output from its origin (which is 'AAAA')?**

Comment: i google "How to Encrypt password in SQL" and find this post!!!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe pwdencrypt is using a hash so you cannot really reverse the hashed string - the algorithm is designed so it's impossible.

If you are verifying the password that a user entered the usual technique is to hash it and then compare it to the hashed version in the database.

This is how you could verify a usered entered table

```
SELECT password_field FROM mytable WHERE password_field=pwdencrypt(userEnteredValue)
```

Replace userEnteredValue with (big surprise) the value that the user entered :)

Comment: pwdencrypt() returns a different result after each call - you cannot compare a password by comparing two hashes made with pwdencrypt. Instead you have to use pwdcompare('plaintext psw', 'hashed psw') to correctly compare them.

Comment: Just a note, the hashes are irreversible because it's possible that two different strings could equal the same hash. In that way it's impossible to know what it originally was. It's just incredibly unlikely to come across two strings that equal the same hash, but it makes the hash more secure by not being able to decrypt it.

Comment: More accurately, you cannot decrypt a hash because a hash contains no encrypted data. Hashing != encrypting. Hashing is a lossy operation, encryption is not.

Comment: More importantly, you cannot reverse a hash because hashing is a lossy operation.  By design, there is information missing so that the hashed value cannot be used to recreate the original, insufficient information is available.  The only hope of "reversal", assuming one knows the hash algorithm and salt, would be to generate a rainbow table of sorts to look up the hash's original value(s). -

Answer (score 26):

The SQL Server password hashing algorithm:

```
hashBytes = 0x0100 | fourByteSalt | SHA1(utf16EncodedPassword+fourByteSalt)
```

For example, to hash the password *"correct horse battery staple"*. First we generate some random salt:

```
fourByteSalt = 0x9A664D79;
```

And then hash the password (encoded in UTF-16) along with the salt:

```
 SHA1("correct horse battery staple" + 0x9A66D79);
=SHA1(0x63006F007200720065006300740020006200610074007400650072007900200068006F00720073006500200073007400610070006C006500 0x9A66D79)
=0x6EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3
```

The value stored in the **`syslogins`** table is the concatenation of:

> [header] + [salt] + [hash]
> `0x0100` `9A664D79` `6EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3`

Which you can see in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
   name, CAST(password AS varbinary(max)) AS PasswordHash
FROM sys.syslogins
WHERE name = 'sa'

name  PasswordHash
====  ======================================================
sa    0x01009A664D796EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3
```

- Version header: `0100`
- Salt (four bytes): `9A664D79`
- Hash: `6EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3` *(SHA-1 is 20 bytes; 160 bits)*

### Validation

You validate a password by performing the same hash:

- grab the salt from the saved `PasswordHash`: 0x9A664D79

and perform the hash again:

```
SHA1("correct horse battery staple" + 0x9A66D79);
```

which will come out to the same hash, and you know the password is correct.

### What once was good, but now is weak

The hashing algorithm introduced with SQL Server 7, in 1999, was good for 1999.

- It is good that the password hash salted.
- It is good to **append** the salt to the password, rather than **prepend** it.

But today it is out-dated. It only runs the hash once, where it should run it a few thousand times, in order to thwart brute-force attacks.

In fact, Microsoft's Baseline Security Analyzer will, as part of it's checks, attempt to bruteforce passwords. If it guesses any, it reports the passwords as weak. And it does get some.

## Brute Forcing

To help you test some passwords:

```
DECLARE @hash varbinary(max)
SET @hash = 0x01009A664D796EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3
--Header: 0x0100
--Salt:   0x9A664D79
--Hash:   0x6EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3

DECLARE @password nvarchar(max)
SET @password = 'password'

SELECT
    @password AS CandidatePassword,
    @hash AS PasswordHash,
    
    --Header
    0x0100
    +
    --Salt
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @hash), 2, 2))
    +
    --SHA1 of Password + Salt
    HASHBYTES('SHA1', @password + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @hash), 2, 2))
```

### SQL Server 2012 and SHA-512

Starting with SQL Server 2012, Microsoft switched to using SHA-2 512-bit:

```
hashBytes = 0x0200 | fourByteSalt | SHA512(utf16EncodedPassword+fourByteSalt)
```

Changing the version prefix to `0x0200`:

```
SELECT 
   name, CAST(password AS varbinary(max)) AS PasswordHash
FROM sys.syslogins

name  PasswordHash
----  --------------------------------
xkcd  0x02006A80BA229556EB280AA7818FAF63A0DA8D6B7B120C6760F0EB0CB5BB320A961B04BD0836 0C0E8CC4C326220501147D6A9ABD2A006B33DEC99FCF1A822393FC66226B7D38
```

- Version: `0200` *(SHA-2 512-bit)*
- Salt: `6A80BA22`
- Hash (64 bytes): `9556EB280AA7818FAF63A0DA8D6B7B120C6760F0EB0CB5BB320A961B04BD0836 0C0E8CC4C326220501147D6A9ABD2A006B33DEC99FCF1A822393FC66226B7D38`

This means we hash the UTF-16 encoded password, with the salt suffix:

- SHA512(*"correct horse battery staple"*+`6A80BA22`)
- SHA512(`63006f0072007200650063007400200068006f0072007300650020006200610074007400650072007900200073007400610070006c006500` + `6A80BA22`)
- `9556EB280AA7818FAF63A0DA8D6B7B120C6760F0EB0CB5BB320A961B04BD0836 0C0E8CC4C326220501147D6A9ABD2A006B33DEC99FCF1A822393FC66226B7D38`

Comment: FYI the hashing algorithms have changed in recent versions of SQL server. See http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-1474.html

Comment: It's `UTF-16LE` to be more precise (PHP's `sha1(mb_convert_encoding("...", 'UTF-16')...)` fails otherwise)

Answer (score 12):

You realise that you may be making a rod for your own back for the future. The pwdencrypt() and pwdcompare() are undocumented functions and may not behave the same in future versions of SQL Server.

Why not hash the password using a predictable algorithm such as SHA-2 or better before hitting the DB?

Comment: Or by `HASHBYTES('sha1', 'password')`.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't really be de-encrypting passwords.

You should be encrypting the password entered into your application and comparing against the encrypted password from the database.

Edit - and if this is because the password has been forgotten, then setup a mechanism to create a new password.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot decrypt this password again but there is another method named "pwdcompare". Here is a example how to use it with SQL syntax:

```
USE TEMPDB
GO
declare @hash varbinary (255)
CREATE TABLE tempdb..h (id_num int, hash varbinary (255))
SET @hash = pwdencrypt('123') -- encryption
INSERT INTO tempdb..h (id_num,hash) VALUES (1,@hash)
SET @hash = pwdencrypt('123')
INSERT INTO tempdb..h (id_num,hash) VALUES (2,@hash)
SELECT TOP 1 @hash = hash FROM tempdb..h WHERE id_num = 2
SELECT pwdcompare ('123', @hash) AS [Success of check] -- Comparison
SELECT * FROM tempdb..h
INSERT INTO tempdb..h (id_num,hash) 
VALUES (3,CONVERT(varbinary (255),
0x01002D60BA07FE612C8DE537DF3BFCFA49CD9968324481C1A8A8FE612C8DE537DF3BFCFA49CD9968324481C1A8A8))
SELECT TOP 1 @hash = hash FROM tempdb..h WHERE id_num = 3
SELECT pwdcompare ('123', @hash) AS [Success of check] -- Comparison
SELECT * FROM tempdb..h
DROP TABLE tempdb..h
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=pwdencrypt) indicates that pwdencrypt() is not deterministic, and your statement select pwdencrypt('AAAA') returns a different value on my installation!

See also this article http://www.theregister.co.uk/2002/07/08/cracking_ms_sql_server_passwords/

Comment: The pwdencrypt() method returns a different hash for each call - anyhow the pwdcompare() method can compare two hashes.