# Decrypt the password column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

I start working on an old software of which I just forget the password. I go through the SQL Server 2008 database and found it is saved in the encrypted form

```
0xA77F9B75A183A3836540FBBE11963F771ED41BBE
```

there. I want to decrypt the password column and want to know the real password. So that I can access my application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173329/how-to-decrypt-a-password-from-sql-server

Comment: Unless you know how this was encrypted, it'll be hard or impossible to decrypt it. Also: if it's not been encrypted but **hashed**, then there's no way to reverse it back to the original

Answer (score -1):

therewere no way you can decrypted, but if MD5 you could try the fallowing http://www.md5online.org/ they will cracked for you. but if you were unhappy with this answer and your programm is valuable for, try this http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/