# How can I get SQL Server User Credentials?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my local PC, I have SQL Server 2008.
I forgot my SQL Server User Credentials.
How can I get it back?

Comment: Can you log in as the sa user or an admin who can reset the account?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the dba site.

Comment: If you mean Password, you can't - you'll need to use another account that has admin rights and reset the password.  local machine admins typically have admin rights to SQL Server as well.

Comment: no, that password I forgot...

Comment: Google for `"SQL Server" standalone mode`. Also [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com) is more on topic for that - it's a sister site of Stack Overflow, your question would be more on topic there.

Comment: Think really hard. If needed, reinstall SQL Server.

Comment: Backup all databases and do a re-install.

Comment: No need to reinstall - also check this out: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49677/no-sa-password-no-sql-server-management-studio-no-os-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just log-in using window authentication and reset the password.

This may help you:
[how to change sql server login password](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/39ad1085-6c8c-476b-a84a-01b16f39211e/how-to-change-sql-server-login-password?forum=sqlsecurity)

Answer (score 0):

In the DB called "master", you can view them with:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.syslogins
```

However passwords are encrypted.

Comment: can we decrypt password?

Comment: @SanketS - Well can you login to run this query in the first place first? If so what is your actual issue?

Comment: @SanketS Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173329/how-to-decrypt-a-password-from-sql-server