# How to decrypt a password from MS SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, hash

I study SQLInjection testing it on one site, that use Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

```
sqlmap-dev$ python sqlmap.py -u "https://site?id=239" --current-user --current-db -b --users --privileges --passwords
```

Receive users login and hashed password:

**Like this:** 0x01005847e7a1ffa21b9c6811420f0e502612c8dd976f685f63a6

The question is, how I can know it?

I understand that I cannot really reverse the hashed string.

I find this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154134/2264941

As I understand:

```
0x0100 - use SHA1
5847e7a1 - salt
ffa21b9c6811420f0e502612c8dd976f685f63a6 - hashed password with salt
```

Is this algoritm correct for MS SQL 2008 ?
Maybe there is some online instruments that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. That is literally the whole point in hashing and salting... You could try a password cracker but it will take A LONG TIME.

Comment: As I understand I need to take sha1(password + 5847e7a1) and if it equal to ffa21b9c6811420f0e502612c8dd976f685f63a6 I find it. Correct?

Comment: But you do not know the password - you only have the RESULT of the Sha1 + salt operation. The ENTIRE POINT in this operation is it is hard to reverse... It wouldn't be very secure if you could turn them back would it? Online Banking and all other security would not work in that case....

Comment: I understand it, But I can take 500 the worst password by dictionary, add salt and make sha1, Correct?

Comment: You can certainly try that, if you suspect they have used a poor password... Good luck with that.

Comment: But if that is your approach, you could simply try to log in with those 500 passwords using a script, which will be easier, and cut out any potential issues with you thinking you know the salt... why do you think you know the salt value? Where did you get that from?

Comment: Is it salt not a part of hashed password?

Comment: The salt is ADDED to the password (before it is hashed) in order to prevent Rainbow Table attacks (which are where lots of password are hashed and the hash is just looked up from that list), the salt ensures that the hash generated is different per application or instance. Why do you think you know what the salt value is? It should vary per server... Read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)