# compute mssql password_hash with php?

Tags: php, sql-server

i want to calculate a mssql `password_hash` with php

i suspect the problem is the hex format of the salt

i have tried all possible combinations of `mb_convert_encoding (§password,"UTF-16")`, `bin2hex` and `hex2bin` without success

can someone please give me a hint

my mssql server is a newer version

my test password is `test0815` and tried `sha512` without success

i found this example

[How to decrypt a password from SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173329/how-to-decrypt-a-password-from-sql-server)

```
@x01009A664D796EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3
--Header:0x0100
--Salt: 0x9A664D79
--Hash: Ox6EDB2FA35E3B8FAB4DBA2FFB62F5426B67FE54A3
```

my code

```
$password-"password".    
echo hash("SHA1“, $password . ex9A664D79 );
```

the hash did not match

—-

i use a a copy of the SQL Server login data with a mariadb database the user should use the same password in 2 different programs

I can‘t use PWDENCRYPT() function on SQL Server

Comment: 1) hashing is not encryption. Hashes are not reversible. You can try and compare them, but that's all. 2) without knowing how your hashed value was created in SQL Server, we can't advise you on how to replicate the process. But I would suggest doing it in SQL, not PHP, for ease.

Comment: How do you calculate hash in SQL Server?

Comment: Are you actually talking about the hashed password for say, a SQL login/user?

Comment: From linked thread seems like `pwdcompare` is the answer

Comment: `i use a a copy of the SQL Server login data with a mariadb database the user should use the same password in 2 different programs`...in that case the simplest thing would probably be to reset all the passwords and rehash the passwords using password_hash, and then use php's password_verify in the php application to verify them when they log in. You aren't going to be able to replicate a hashing algorithm you know nothing about. Just start again.

Answer (score 0):

The [PWDENCRYPT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql) function on SQL Server is poorly named. It is not an encryption function, it is a salt-and-hashing function.

Its algorithm is undocumented and is subject to change, and it has actually changed several times already since SQL Server 6.5 days. Its exact nature is not something that should be relied upon.

The version currently deployed to SQL Server 2014-2022, for example, can be shown to use a SHA2_512 hash of a 4 byte salt and a Unicode password, e.g.:

```sql
declare @pwdencrypt varbinary(max) = ( select pwdencrypt('HELLO, WORLD!') );
declare @version binary(2) = substring(@pwdencrypt, 1, 2);
declare @salt binary(4) = substring(@pwdencrypt, 3, 4);

select @pwdencrypt as [pwdencrypt];
select @version + @salt + hashbytes('SHA2_512', convert(varbinary, N'HELLO, WORLD!') + @salt) as [salt-and-hash];
```

| pwdencrypt |
| --- |
| 0x0200E4D6EDEA883603E9BFFD406BA270E1F1717EFA84E837E8CD39DE2863B35B8C44BBD31A963331F4E30EF271A07B1C84C04052258631295B90829FD50F8688F8F892582F75 |

| salt-and-hash |
| --- |
| 0x0200E4D6EDEA883603E9BFFD406BA270E1F1717EFA84E837E8CD39DE2863B35B8C44BBD31A963331F4E30EF271A07B1C84C04052258631295B90829FD50F8688F8F892582F75 |